# How to use enums with codes in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, enums

**enum**

```
public enum ArticlePublishStatus {
    DRAFT ("DRAFT"),
    SUBMITTED ("SUB"),
    PUBLISHED ("PUB");

    private final String code;

    private ArticlePublishStatus(String code) {   
        this.code=code;   
    }   
}
```

**Screen Object (aka form backing object)**

```
public class ArticleHeaderEditScreenObject extends EditScreenObject {
    private Integer articleId;
    private String title;
    private ArticlePublishStatus publishStatus;
```

**View**

```
<form:select path="publishStatus"
    items="${screenObject.getArticlePublishStatusOptionList()}" 
    itemLabel="label" 
    itemValue="value" />
```

**html**

```
<select id="publishStatus" name="publishStatus">
    <option value="DRAFT" selected="selected">Draft</option>
    <option value="SUB">Submitted</option>
    <option value="PUB">Published</option>
</select>
```

**Exception**

Draft works fine, as the name and code of corresponding enum are the same. Saving the page with Submitted or Published fails.

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type com.siteadmin.domain.ArticlePublishStatus for value 'PUB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.siteadmin.domain.ArticlePublishStatus.PUB`

`org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.siteadmin.domain.ArticlePublishStatus.PUB 
java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)`

I see that it's having problems selecting enum based on its code but I still have not figured out what to do about it. There's lots on the subject of enums but haven't found anything that would help this one. Is there a method that enum needs implemented to address it?

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing the implementation of `getArticlePublishStatusOptionList()`, this a bit of a guess...

If you used the `toString` value of `ArticlePublishStatus` as the value part of the Option returned from `getArticlePublishStatusOptionList()`, then the Spring MVC Enum Converter could bind your enum using `.valueOf`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<option value="SUB">Submitted</option>
<option value="PUB">Published</option>
```

Spring use .valueOf("SUBMITTED"); to convert the value to enum. It has nothing to do with the enum internal value.

See [What is the reason for java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class even though iterating through values() works just fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639791/what-is-the-reason-for-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-enum-const-class-e)