# What is the reason for java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class even though iterating through values() works just fine?

Tags: java, enums

This question is basically an extension of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639038/when-do-enum-instances-get-created) . I asked the previous question to be sure that the Enum constants are populated when the class loads . Here's is my class again with the addition of a simple method `getByName` :

```
public enum PropName {

  CONTENTS("contents"),
  USE_QUOTES("useQuotes"),
  ONKEYDOWN("onkeydown"),
  BROWSER_ENTIRE_TABLE("browseEntireTable"),
  COLUMN_HEADINGS("columnHeadings"),
  PAGE_SIZE("pageSize"),
  POPUP_TITLE("popupTitle"),
  FILTER_COL("filterCol"),
  SQL_SELECT("sqlSelect"),
  ;

  private String name;

  private PropName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public static PropName getByName(String name){
    return   PropName.valueOf(name);
  }
}
```

A call to the method `getByName("columnHeadings")` is throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class labware.web.component.limsgrid.PropName.columnHeadings` but if I replace this method with the following code it just works .

```
 public static PropName getByName(String name){
    for(PropName prop : values()){
      if(prop.getName().equals(name)){
        return prop;
      }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " is not a valid PropName");
  }
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You really should not define a property named "name" in your enum. You'll have name() and getName() returning different value...

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`Enum.valueOf()` only checks the constant name, so you need to pass it `"COLUMN_HEADINGS"` instead of "columnHeadings". Your `name` property has nothing to do with Enum internals.

---

To address the questions/concerns in the comments:

The enum's "builtin" (implicitly declared) `valueOf(String name)` method will look up an enum constant with that exact name. If your input is "columnHeadings", you have (at least) three choices:

1. Forget about the naming conventions for a bit and just name your constants as it makes most sense: `enum PropName { contents, columnHeadings, ...}`. This is obviously the most convenient.
2. Convert your camelCase input into UPPER_SNAKE_CASE before calling `valueOf`, if you're really fond of naming conventions.
3. Implement your own lookup method instead of the builtin `valueOf` to find the corresponding constant for an input. This makes most sense if there are multiple possible mappings for the same set of constants.

Comment: What if you need to map that exactly that way? You have "columnHeadings" coming from somewhere else and need to use it as COLUMN_HEADINGS enum in the code?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here!  One might ask what the point is of the associated type if you can't map to an enum using the raw value.  I might be missing something.

Answer (score 12):

That's because you defined your own version of `name` for your enum, and `getByName` doesn't use that.

`getByName("COLUMN_HEADINGS")` would probably work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining: `COLUMN_HEADINGS("columnHeadings")`

Try defining it as:  `COLUMNHEADINGS("columnHeadings")`

Then when you call `getByName(String name) method`, call it with the upper-cased String like this: `getByName(myStringVariable.toUpperCase())`

I had the same problem as you, and this worked for me.

Comment: This force you to have exactly (caseinsensitive) same enum name and property value.

Answer (score 1):

I had parsing enum problem when i was trying to pass **Nullable Enum** that we get from Backend.
Of course it was working when we get value, but it was problem when the null comes up.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant

Also the problem was when we at Parcelize read moment write some *short if*.

My solution for this was

**1.Create companion object with parsing method.**

```
enum class CarsType {
    @Json(name = "SMALL")
    SMALL,
    @Json(name = "BIG")
    BIG;

    companion object {
        fun nullableValueOf(name: String?) = when (name) {
            null -> null
            else -> valueOf(name)
        }
    }
}
```

**2. In Parcerable read place use it like this**

```
data class CarData(
    val carId: String? = null,
    val carType: CarsType?,
    val data: String?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        CarsType.nullableValueOf(parcel.readString()),
        parcel.readString())
```